# crash shell: any way to check if a command executed Successfully

Tags: linux, utilities, crash

I'm automating a test using crash package. Is there some thing like `$?`, which can be used to check if the previous command executed successfully or not inside a  crash shell?

For example, when command:

```
crash> bt -a
```

Is executed, how do I know if it was successful or not? The only solution in my mind is greping through the results, but it's not reliable when the environment changes.

This is what i get when I try `echo $?`:

```
crash> bt asd
bt: invalid task or pid value: asd
crash> $?
crash: command not found: $?
crash> echo $?
0
crash>
crash> q
root@at0012-ubuntu:~/crashKernel#
```

`$?` always appears to be 0.

I already asked this question on superuser a few days back, but no help from there. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I only know of `crash` as something that analyses a Linux dump (under Ubuntu). Where do you get the prompt from (installed package + command)?

Comment: [This](http://www.crashub.org/reference.html) might be of help. Assuming this is the JVM shell.

Comment: @Anthon start crash using `crash <crashDump> <kernel>` it will drop you in `crash>` shell where you can run the crash commands to analyze the crash.

Comment: what I am talking about is [this](http://linux.die.net/man/8/crash)

Comment: @AbhishekLal sorry, we are talking about the same, but I would not call that a shell (neither does the crash documentation).

Comment: @AbhishekLal that documentation says nothing about an `echo` command.

Comment: @Anthon - http://people.redhat.com/anderson/crash_whitepaper/ - the `echo` command shows up there.

Comment: @slm I might read that wrong, but isn't `echo` there an example of how to add new code and they use that as an example on how to extend `crash`?

Comment: @Anthon - on second look, you'd be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry -- I misunderstood the original question.

The answer is no, there is no way to tell whether a crash utility command has completed successfully.  The functions that are called to perform a command are all void functions, e.g., the "bt" command is declared like so:

void
cmd_bt(void)
{
...
}

Answer (score 2):

As hinted by @Anthon, this is not a "normal" *nix shell like Bash or Dash, but rather an application-specific prompt (`q` is not a [POSIX built-in utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/idx/sbi.html) for example). From a quick look through [`man crash`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/crash) it looks like there is no command to get the exit code of the last command.

Answer (score 0):

As @l0b0 already clarified this is not a `normal` shell. Apart from that it does not seem to have have `echo` as a command you can type at your prompt.
Compare:

```
crash -h bt
```

with

```
crash -h echo
```

you would probably get the same result `0` if you tried at the `crash>` prompt:

```
spam ?0
```

Comment: There is echo command `crash> help echo` gives some help for echo _Print a constant string.  Give string as argument. C escape sequences may be used in the argument....._

Answer (score 0):

The crash utility's "bt" command gives you the stack backtrace of a given task's last entry into kernel mode, be it via syscall or exception.  It has no concept of the status of a task that no longer exists, i.e., one that was previously executed by a bash shell.